# If $F=m\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ why is it incorrect to write $F\,dt=m\,dv$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, infinitesimals

`My university lecturer told me that:`

> If $$F=m\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$ it's incorrect to write $$F\,dt=m\,dv\tag{1}$$ but it *is* okay to write $$\int F\,dt=\int m\,dv$$ for Newtons' second law.

But never explained why $(1)$ is mathematically incorrect.

`My high school teacher told me that:`

> Derivatives with respect to one independent variable can be treated as fractions.

So this implies that $(1)$ is valid.

This is clearly a contradiction as my high school teacher and university lecturer **cannot** both be correct. Or can they?

Another example of this misuse of derivatives uses the specific heat capacity $c$ which is defined to be $$c=\frac{1}{m}\frac{\delta Q}{dT}\tag{2}$$

Now in the same vain another lecturer wrote that $$\delta Q=mc\,dT$$ by rearranging $(2)$.

Another contraction to the first lecturer. I this *really* allowed **or** if it's invalid then which mathematical 'rule' has been violated here?

---

### EDIT:

In my question here I have used formulae that belong to Physics but these were just simple examples to illustrate the point. My question is much more general and applies to *any* differential equation in mathematics involving the treatment of derivatives with respect to one independent variable as fractions.

Specifically; Why is it 'strictly' incorrect to rearrange them without taking the integral of both sides?

Comment: This is a question about useful intuition vs formal correctness. I agree with the second lecturer. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812327/what-is-the-logic-behind-decomposing-a-derivative-operator-symbol-in-the-popula/1812354#1812354, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977134/most-useful-heuristic/1978539#1978539

Comment: It's usually okay to write $Fdt=mdv$. But your university lecturer may have some reasons behind by saying it's incorrect, so you should ask him/her for details.

Comment: You **can** write $F\,dt=m\,dv$ if you mean differential forms. Note, that $\delta Q$ isn't *exact* differential form, so you can't write it as $dQ$.

Comment: The fact that it can be written as $F\,dt=m\,dv$ without anything going wrong is the beauty of the Leibniz notation of differentials. There are plenty of questions here (apart from the marked duplicate) regarding this only. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906241/when-not-to-treat-dy-dx-as-a-fraction-in-single-variable-calculus/)] post has the links of the related posts as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your lecturer is telling you that, on its own, the expression $dt$ is meaningless, whereas $\int...dt$ does mean something quite specific, i.e. an operator or instruction to integrate with respect to $t$.

In contrast, $\delta t$ does mean something specific, i.e. a small increment in the value of $t$.

However, most people are fairly casual about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is not so much between university lecturers and highschool teachers as between mathematicians and physicists. *Some* mathematicians tend to frown on certain procedures that are perfectly acceptable to physicists. I was careful to write "some" because mathematicians familiar with Robinson's framework with infinitesimals do assign a perfectly rigorous meaning to formulas like $F\, dt = m\, dv$; see Keisler's beautiful textbook [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely,

$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$$

$$\int F\, dt=\Delta p$$

If $\dfrac{dm}{dt}=0$, then $$\int F\, dt=m\int dv$$

Comment: In classical Mechanics $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$

Comment: @RAM, That's not true for rockets.

Comment: Yes,In theory of relativity that is not true.

Comment: @RAM, See [**rocket principle**](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rocket.html#c2)

Comment: Yes i agree with you. I said dm/dt=0 is not true